# Runtimeerror 1004 when trying to delete a row in an inactive protected Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am trying to delete a row in an inactive protected Worksheet via VBA. Without protection the deleting works fine.

I'm setting the Worksheet-Protection in the Workbook_Open-Sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Password As String
    Password = "123"

    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
    For Each myWorksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        myWorksheet.Protect Password:=Password, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password

End Sub
```

The Error is thrown in the first line of the following code:

```
Public Sub DeleteRow(Row As Integer)
    Rows(Row).Delete

    [...]

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? The strange thing is that I can delete a row in an active protected Worksheet.
Please help me!

Marco

Comment: `I am trying to delete a row in an inactive protected Worksheet ` - but `Rows(Row).Delete` deletes row always in _active_ sheet. To delete row in another sheet use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(Row).Delete`

Comment: The DeleteRow sub is in the worksheet object where I want to delete the row. So using the name of the worksheet in front does not make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: try to use it in `standart module`.

Comment: Now it is saying: "Runtimerror 1004: The Delete-Method of the Range-Object could not be executed" (freely translated from German)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered adding a line of code to unprotect your sheets when the macro wants to start execution and adding a line to protect the sheets just before the macro finishes?

Comment: This works for me although it does not look very nice. I am deleting 5 rows from 5 different worksheets and you can see that Excel is going through them very fast when protecting and unprotecting. But I am happy it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: I used `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the code and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after the code so the user cannot see that Excel is going through all worksheets to delete the rows.